# How to convert UUID

Tags: uuid, uniqueidentifier, distributed-system

I'm trying to generate cluster-wide unique ID's in a distributed system and I have chosen to generate UUID’s. UUID’s are 128 bits hexadecimal numbers which have a very very very low probability of getting generated twice. My question is how would I convert the hex string into a long value? Below are my code and its output. I tried different way but I keep getting an exception.

**Code:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    System.out.println("Generated UUID: " + uuid );
}
```

**Output:**

```
Generated UUID: 7a8c2c99-a378-4481-a4d5-0b90dae8d220
Generated UUID: d93da730-a261-4617-a0cb-eaa3441a956d
Generated UUID: bfaa2c28-fbde-42aa-a3ff-3db0709b5fa9
Generated UUID: df131f0c-b3aa-4132-bcc7-1268f21b0a1b
Generated UUID: 066ecfd0-144b-441d-848a-8b2b425d93f8
Generated UUID: aeaabb6b-a03e-4afe-ac2e-a08902c8490c
Generated UUID: 19953f8d-b9f5-418e-9577-6222ef3ab3f8
Generated UUID: d936862f-7e63-4384-9694-24714b8953ab
Generated UUID: f0f979e4-d570-4867-afc0-fbf92ef3c570
Generated UUID: e504165f-823e-4dea-b520-a323032bd37c
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. The primitive type `long` in Java is a 64-bit type. You can't fit 128 bits in 64 bits without loss of information.